# Firebird query - include value from next row

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table with the following columns (very simplified):

```
CustomerID | ValidFrom | ValidTo
----------------------------------
1          | 20180101  | 20180330
2          | 20180601  | 20181003
1          | 20180212  | 20180313
```

I have found a query to achieve the following result:

```
CustomerID | ValidFrom
-----------------------
1          | 20180101
1          | 20180212
1          | 20180314
1          | 20180331
2          | 20180601   
2          | 20181004
```

query:

```
SELECT CustomerID, ValidFrom
FROM table
UNION
SELECT CustomerID, ValidTo + 1
FROM table
```

But how can I achieve the following result (almost the value from next row included in previous row)?

```
CustomerID | ValidFrom | ValidTo
---------------------------------
1          | 20180101  | 20180211
1          | 20180212  | 20180313
1          | 20180314  | 20180330
1          | 20180331  | NULL
2          | 20180601  | 20181003
2          | 20181004  | NULL
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result from your second query by using [SQL window functions](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html):

```
select
    validfrom
  , lag(validfrom,1) over (partition by customerId, order by validFrom)
  from (
      SELECT CustomerID, ValidFrom
      FROM table
      UNION
      SELECT CustomerID, ValidTo + 1
      FROM table
  ) foo
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into that direction! I'm using the lead function now.